# Why would you distribute replica shards across nodes and not mirror replicas?

Tags: replication

I'm trying to understand how replicas work in Elasticsearch.

[image]

This is a very basic question, but can someone explain why one node is not just all replicas? Surely in this example, if one node fails 50% of the shards will be lost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, there are two nodes.

The data is represented at 4 data set shards: A, B, C, D.

Both nodes hold all 4 data sets, with each node as primary writable shard for 2 data sets, and secondary (read only) replica shards for 2 data sets.

This allows you to spread workload across both nodes, with each node serving half of the workload. In the event if a node failure, the secondary replica data sets can be made primary on the other node, with a single node serving 100% of the workload. There is no data loss because A, B, C, & D exist on both nodes.

Comment: You may want to clarify that this is specifically to distribute _writes_, because they happen on primary shards first. _Reads_ could be distributed even if there were only one node holding all primary shards.